# How to get className after creating jQuery variable

Tags: jquery

I would like to set a jQuery variable, then target a `className` by doing something like this:

```
var chosen_language = '#English';

if (this.className == chosen_language) {
    blah blah blah;
}
```

But the above does not seem to work because I have 3 separate classes here.  The HTML looks something like this below:

```
<a id="English" class"English nturl en" href="#">English</a>
```

How can I target ONLY the 3rd class (i.e. `en`), using the exact example that I have above?

Comment: Class Names don't start with English... See my answer bellow

Answer (score 4):

With jQuery :

```
if ($(this).hasClass(chosen_language)) { };
```

Comment: I'm trying to target only class `en`, how would I be able to do that?

Comment: if ($(this).hasClass('en')) { };

Comment: Yep, that worked.  I'm having an off day - so easy.  Thank you!

Comment: one question: I should have asked how to get the name of the 3rd class, based on the ID of `#English`.  `#English` will always be changing, so I cannot use `en` because it needs to be variable.  How can I dynamically get classname of `en`?